# I need to set seekbar value from -100 to 100 for user display only

Tags: java, android, seekbar

Hi I am newbie in android development

Currently I am working on video filter contracts , I have set the value for `SeekBar` from 0-60 and its work fine but my requirement is to display user the `SeekBar` values from -100 to 100

Here I just need to visualise users that -100 to 100 values are using to set contrast but internally i would like to set 0-60 value

How can i achieved this functionality

I know this question is based on login but i need all folks expert advice

Help will be really appriciated

Thanks

Comment: set the values `0..200`, and show it as `seekbar_value - 100`

Comment: But internally i just want to use values form 0-60 and i want to display value -100 to 100 to user

Comment: how do you want to convert -100 .. 100 to 0 .. 60?

Answer (score 2):

Your SeekBar min must be 0 and max 200 *(= 100 - (-100))*

Then show the user: `seekBarValue - 100`

and your intern value is `seekBarValue / (200/60)`